# IP hijacking during SSL

Tags: tls

I was wondering, does SSL protect from IP hijacking (an active, authenticated connection between two hosts is disrupted and the attacker takes the place of one of the hosts) and how?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of certificate is to verify the identity of the server you are communicating with.

Comment: I think you need to define "hijacking" a little more. Man-in-the-middle is still a problem even though the browser will alert that the SSL certificate does not match. Are you referring to MITM?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal of the hijack is to disrupt the secure connection, then yes (but of course you can disrupt things by cutting wires, so no amount of crypto can really protect you).

If the goal of the hijack is to take the place of one of the hosts, then no. The impostor can neither decrypt the incoming data nor inject intelligible data into the stream.